# Intersection of paths connecting vertices of convex hull

Tags: geometry, convex-hulls

Suppose we have a set of $n$ points, and suppose that the convex hull of those points contains vertices $i$, $j$, $k$, and $l$, appearing in that order on the convex hull but not necessarily consecutively.

Suppose further that we draw a path from $i$ to $k$ and another path from $j$ to $l$, both paths being contained within the convex hull.

It seems evident to me that the two paths must intersect, but I'm unable to come up with a simple proof. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start of an argument. Consider the region whose "top" edge is the boundary of the convex set from $i$ to $k$ and whose "bottom" edge is the path from $k$ to $i$.

The convexity implies that the path from $j$ to $l$ starts out inside that region and ends up outside. Then the Jordan curve theorem tells you it crosses the boundary. That crossing must be at the bottom edge.

Possible subtleties:

You may need to work a little harder if the bottom edge has self intersections.

Treat the case when three of $ijkl$ are collinear separately.

Comment: Jordan curve theorem -- that's the key I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$i$ is on one side of $\overline{jk}$ and $l$ is on the other side of $\overline{jk}$.  The definition of convexity is that if $i$ and $l$ are in the set, the *straight line* joining them is in the set.

QED.

Comment: But the paths need not be straight line segments. How can we be sure they don't snake around one another and avoid intersecting?

Comment: I agree that the straight line joining $i$ and $l$ is in the set; but that doesn't imply that any path in the set is a straight line, or that any such path must intersect a (not necessarily straight) path from $j$ to $k$.